# How to get a single record in a one to many relation based on the value of this record

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have two tables, one contains a list of projects, another contains requests for this project. I would like to get the project number and the requests record. The status can be: Red, Yellow, Green, Open

How can I make sure that the 1 status record being shown follows the logic that when there is a Red one, show the red one, when there is no red one but there is a yellow one show this yellow one so on...

```
;WITH 
numberTest as(
    SELECT dbo.ServiceRequest.ID as numId,
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID order by     Project_ID) AS RN1
    FROM dbo.ServiceRequest         
),

CTEVrequest AS
(
    SELECT dbo.ServiceRequest.ID,   dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID   
    FROM         dbo.ServiceRequest     
    LEFT JOIN    numberTest ON numberTest.numId = dbo.ServiceRequest.ID 
    WHERE numberTest.RN1 = 1
    AND 
    dbo.ServiceRequest.ID = CASE 

    WHEN EXISTS( 
    select srvReq.ID
    from  dbo.ServiceRequest as srvReq  
    where requestStatus.ServiceStatus = 'R' AND srvReq.Project_ID =     dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID)
    THEN (select srvReq.ID
    from  dbo.ServiceRequest as srvReq  
    where requestStatus.ServiceStatus = 'R' AND srvReq.Project_ID =     dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID) 

    WHEN EXISTS( 
    select srvReq.ID
    from  dbo.ServiceRequest as srvReq  
    where requestStatus.ServiceStatus = 'Y' AND srvReq.Project_ID =     dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID)
    THEN (select srvReq.ID
    from  dbo.ServiceRequest as srvReq  
    where requestStatus.ServiceStatus = 'Y' AND srvReq.Project_ID =     dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID) 
END) 

SELECT  DISTINCT
    dbo.Project.ProjectNumber, 
    dbo.Project.ID, 
    CTEVrequest.ServiceReqStatus,
    CTEVrequest.ServiceStatus                    
    FROM         dbo.Project
    LEFT JOIN    CTEVrequest ON CTEVrequest.Project_ID = dbo.Project.ID
    LEFT JOIN     dbo.Project ON dbo.ServiceRequest.Project_ID = dbo.Project.ID
```

The problem is I get the "Subquery returned more than 1 value" error and I have no clue how to make the result check if there exists a record with Red and if not select the one with Yellow and so on.

Comment: Here is a great place to start. http://spaghettidba.com/2015/04/24/how-to-post-a-t-sql-question-on-a-public-forum/

Comment: Others may not be able to understand/read total code,so best way is to read link posted above by sean

Comment: further,one place where you can see additional columns is (select srvReq.ID...adding select top 1 srvReq.ID may work ,but it doesnt give you results you need

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Probably I did not understand you right, but looks like your query is supposed to do this:

```
SELECT *
FROM dbo.Project p
OUTER APPLY
(
    SELECT TOP 1 sr.*
    FROM dbo.ServiceRequest sr
    WHERE sr.Project_ID = p.Project_ID
      /* AND sr.ServiceStatus in ('R', 'Y') */
    ORDER BY
      CASE
        WHEN sr.ServiceStatus = 'R' THEN 1
        WHEN sr.ServiceStatus = 'Y' THEN 2
        ELSE 3
      END
) sr
```

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you create a table that functions as a key for the statuses? For example:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#LevelKey') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE #LevelKey;

CREATE TABLE #LevelKey 
    (LevelText [varchar](255),
    LevelValue INT);

INSERT INTO #LevelKey VALUES 
    ('Red',1),
    ('Orange',2),
    ('Yellow',3),
    ('Green',4);
```

Now, join the project level to this key. When you want to grab the highest rank, you could do something like:

```
SELECT TOP 1 *
FROM Table
INNER JOIN #LevelKey ON LevelText = Whatever
ORDER BY LevelValue ASC
```

But that only works for one. So I'm not even sure why I included that. To bring back a group, you're going to have to do something like this:

```
SELECT ProjectID, MAX(LevelValue) AS LevelValue
FROM Table
INNER JOIN #LevelKey ON LevelText = Whatever
GROUP BY ProjectID
```